# How to execute a paste function inside a reactive dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, paste, shiny-reactivity

I am somewhat familiar with the `paste()` function in base R. I am trying to learn Shiny and reactivity and don't understand how to execute a `paste()` inside a reactive Shiny function.

In running the demo code at the bottom, this is what first appears in the rendered "Reactive results" panel:

```
  choice subclass
1      A        1
2      A        1
3      A        2
4      B        1
5      B        3
```

I'd like to paste the row number of each row in front of each "choice" column element, followed by a "." and a space, so that the "Reactive results" panel output looks like this:

```
     choice subclass
1      1. A        1
2      2. A        1
3      3. A        2
4      4. B        1
5      5. B        3
```

How would I execute a `paste()` in this reactive example?

Demo code:

```
library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(choice = c("A","A","A","B","B"),subclass = c(1,1,2,1,3))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  h5(strong("Base data frame:")), 
  verbatimTextOutput("data"),
  radioButtons(inputId = "showData",
               label = h5(strong("Multiply base DF subclass by factor of:")),
               choiceNames = c('One','Two'),
               choiceValues = c('One','Two'),
               selected = 'One',
               inline = TRUE
              ),
  h5(strong("Reactive results:")), 
  verbatimTextOutput("choices1")
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  output$data <- renderPrint(data)
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(choices1=c()) 
  
  observeEvent(input$showData, {
      if(input$showData == 'One'){rv$choices1 <- data[]} 
      else {rv$choices1[,2] <- 2 * data[ ,2]}
      }
    )
  
  output[["choices1"]] <- renderPrint({rv$choices1})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app looks a bit complicated to me. But as I don't know about your desired final result I stick with your code and only did some slight changes in your `observeEvent` to achieve your desired result:

```r
library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(choice = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), subclass = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 3))

ui <- fluidPage(
  h5(strong("Base data frame:")),
  verbatimTextOutput("data"),
  radioButtons(
    inputId = "showData",
    label = h5(strong("Multiply base DF subclass by factor of:")),
    choiceNames = c("One", "Two"),
    choiceValues = c("One", "Two"),
    selected = "One",
    inline = TRUE
  ),
  h5(strong("Reactive results:")),
  verbatimTextOutput("choices1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$data <- renderPrint(data)

  rv <- reactiveValues(choices1 = c())

  observeEvent(input$showData, {
    rv$choices1 <- data
    rv$choices1$choice <- paste0(row.names(rv$choices1), ". ", rv$choices1$choice)
    if (input$showData == "Two") {
      rv$choices1[, 2] <- 2 * rv$choices1[, 2]
    }
  })

  output[["choices1"]] <- renderPrint({
    rv$choices1
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4262
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for preserving the overall structure of the App, it's a redaction of another App and I'm trying to understand some of the code in that larger App with this code. One thing that is new to me in your solution Stefan is the the use of two $ symbols in one object:  rv$choices1$choice. What in the world is that doing? Never seen that (though I am pretty new to R)

Comment: You could have three or ... (: In R or ... it's quite common to have some kind of nested list structures, e.g. a list of dataframes like `df_list <- list(a = mtcars, b = iris)`. Now with `df_list$a` we get the element named a which is a df. But if we just want a column of the first element or df we could do `df$a$mpg`. Similarly, in your case `rv` is a kind of list with just one element named `choices1` which contains a dataframe `data` (which columns choice and subclass).

Comment: Great example, df_list <- list(a = mtcars, b = iris), then run df_list$a, run df$list$a$cyl, etc. A nested list structure. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested modifications, in two parts.

First,

- use `str_glue` instead of `paste`, and `mutate` to modify the dataframe,
- replace `choiceNames` and `choiceValues` with a single argument `choices`, as they are equal,
- rewrite `output[["choices1"]]` as `output$choices1`,
- use dataframe column by name rather than by index,
- replace `reactiveValues` and `observeEvent` with a single `reactive`: reactivity is automatic, you don't have to reimplement it with an `oberveEvent`.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

data <- data.frame(choice = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
                   subclass = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 3))

ui <- fluidPage(
  h5(strong("Base data frame:")),
  verbatimTextOutput("data"),
  radioButtons(inputId = "showData",
               label = h5(strong("Multiply base DF subclass by factor of:")),
               choices = c("One", "Two"),
               selected = "One",
               inline = TRUE
  ),
  h5(strong("Reactive results:")),
  verbatimTextOutput("choices1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$data <- renderPrint(data)

  rv <- reactive({
    df <- data %>% mutate(choice = str_glue("{row_number()}. {choice}"))
    if (input$showData == "Two") {
      df %<>% mutate(subclass = 2 * subclass)
    }
    df
  })

  output$choices1 <- renderPrint(rv())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Second simplification: the `reactive` is useless as it's only used once, in `renderPrint`. So put everything in `renderPrint`. It's still reactive.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

data <- data.frame(choice = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
                   subclass = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 3))

ui <- fluidPage(
  h5(strong("Base data frame:")),
  verbatimTextOutput("data"),
  radioButtons(inputId = "showData",
               label = h5(strong("Multiply base DF subclass by factor of:")),
               choices = c("One", "Two"),
               selected = "One",
               inline = TRUE
  ),
  h5(strong("Reactive results:")),
  verbatimTextOutput("choices1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$data <- renderPrint(data)

  output$choices1 <- renderPrint({
    df <- data %>% mutate(choice = str_glue("{row_number()}. {choice}"))
    if (input$showData == "Two") {
      df %<>% mutate(subclass = 2 * subclass)
    }
    df
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```